# I want To Make mcrypt work on xampp windows with php 7.2 Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open()

Tags: php, windows, xampp, mcrypt

For a testing purpose I want to get rid of this error " Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() " . I know its deprecated. Tried pasting the .dll file and addind this line in the php.ini (extension=php_mcrypt 
extension=libmcrypt)  and no use .. Any Help ?

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated was removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`mcrypt` is deprecated in 7.1 and removed in 7.2. Use the built in [`libsodium`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.sodium.php) functionality

Comment: 1. While libsodium is a good secure encryption suite it is not a direct replacement for mcrypt or primitives such as AES. 2. it is **removed** in 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

`mcrypt` is longer used and has now been deprecated since 7.1 and removed in 7.2 as it wasn't being maintained any longer.

You can use functions such as:

- [OpenSSL Encryption](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)
- [Libsodium](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.sodium.php)
- [PHP's inbuilt password hash/verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Using `mcrypt` is not suggested, however downgrading your PHP version will allow you to continue using it without any errors.